# The relationship between the norm of the gradient solution of Poisson's equation in different regions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, poissons-equation

**Question:**

Consider the following two special Poisson equations:
$$\Delta u=-2 \quad \text{in} \quad L$$
$$u=0 \quad \text{on} \quad \partial L$$

and

$$\Delta u=-2 \quad \text{in} \quad W$$
$$u=0 \quad \text{on} \quad \partial W.$$

If $L\subseteq W$, can we get $||\nabla u_{L}||\leqslant ||\nabla u_{W}||$(where $u_{L}$ is the solution of the first equation, and $u_{W}$ is another)?

*I know almost nothing about partial differential equations, and I encountered this problem while working on other problems.*

Comment: Are you using $\Vert\nabla u_L\Vert^2 = \int_L\, \vert\nabla u_L\vert^2$ and $\Vert\nabla u_W\Vert^2 = \int_W\, \vert\nabla u_W\vert^2$?

Comment: @Aruralreader The norm in the question is the Euclidean norm, i.e. $||\nabla u||=\sqrt{<\nabla u,\nabla u>} $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an interesting question, but, unfortunately, it’s false. Let $T\subset \mathbb R^2$ be the equilateral triangle with vertices $(-2,0)$, $(1,\sqrt 3)$, and $(1,-\sqrt 3)$. It is known that $$ u_T(x,y)=-\frac 1 {12} (x-1)(x-\sqrt 3 y +2) (x+\sqrt 3 y +2) $$ satisfies $-\Delta u_T = 1$ in $T$ and $u_T=0$ on $\partial T$. Moreover, if $B_R:= \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \text {s.t. } x^2+y^2 <R^2\}$ then $$ u_{B_R}(x,y) = \frac14 (R^2-x^2-y^2)$$ solves $-\Delta u_{B_R}=1$ in $B_R$ and $u_{B_R}=0$ on $\partial B_R$. Suppose that $R$ is chosen to sufficiently large so that $T \subset B_R$.

Now, by a direct computation, $$\vert \nabla u_T(x,y) \vert^2= \frac 1{ 16} (x^2+2x-y^2)^2+\frac14 y^2 (x-1)^2   $$ and $$ \vert \nabla u_{B_R}(x,y)\vert^2=\frac14 (x^2+y^2). $$ Then $\vert \nabla u_T(0,1) \vert^2= \frac 5{16}$ and $\vert \nabla u_{B_R}(0,1)\vert^2=\frac14 $,  so $$\vert \nabla u_T(x,y) \vert \not \leq \vert \nabla u_{B_R}(x,y)\vert \qquad \text{in } T. $$

Comment: What a wonderful answer!! Thank you! I still want to know that whether $||\nabla u_{L}||\leqslant ||\nabla u_{W}||$ is true on the boundary.

Comment: Doesn’t the OP involve integrals of $\vert \nabla u_T\vert^2$ and $\vert \nabla u_{B_R}\vert^2$ over $T$ and $B_R$, respectively?

Comment: @Aruralreader I think the OP is using $\| \cdot \|$ to refer to the Euclidean norm $\vert \cdot \vert $ not the Dirichlet energy

Comment: @zeyuhao The boundaries of $L$ and $W$ only coincide when $L=W$ (assuming you are taking both of them bounded), so I don’t know what you mean by that inequality holding on “the boundary”

Comment: Thanks @JackT, I suppose you’re right.

Comment: @JackT If $L\subseteq W$, can we get $||\nabla u_{L}(x)||\leqslant ||\nabla u_{W}(y)||$? where $x \in \partial L$, $y \in \partial W$ and $x,y $ are in the same direction.